# What percentage is the rest of the black cars in the parking lot

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Ok so, Last Monday, a parking lot had 80 cars. Of those 80 cars, 25% were silver. 16 were red, and the rest were black. What percent of the cars were black

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What number is $25$% of $80$? OR what percentage is $16$ out of $80$?, if you can answer any one of the two questions then you have solved the problem.

Approach 1: $25$% silver cars out of total $80$ cars is $x$ cars.

So the number of black cars = $80 - (x + 16) $.

Approach 2: 16 red cars of of total 80 cars is $y$%

So the % of black cars =100 - (25 + y)